# $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ defined by $T(f)(t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}f(t)$ find norm of $T$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ and defined by $T(f)(t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}f(t)$

I want to show that $||T||=1/2$

My idea:

$$||Tf||=||\frac{t}{1+t^2}f(t)||=||\frac{t}{1+t^2}||||f(t)||$$

$$||\frac{t}{1+t^2}||=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|\frac{t}{1+t^2}|$$

Since derivative of $\frac{t}{1+t^2}$ is always positive on  $[0,1]$

The supremum of this function is the value at evaluated at $t=1$ so it is $1/2$.

Are these steps complete? Taking derivative feels wrong.

Comment: In general we only have $\lVert \frac{t}{1+t^2} f(t)\rVert \leq \lVert \frac{t}{1+t^2}\rVert \lVert f \rVert$, that is your second equality need not hold. Otherwise what you've done is ok. Note however that this only proves that $\lVert T \rVert \leq 1/2$.

Comment: For the other direction Can I say this?
if I choose $f(t)=1$ then $||f||=1$ and 
$||T||\ge ||Tf||=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|t/(1+t^2)|=1/2$

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale Yes.